# Trying to recreate Space Invaders in Java and I don't understand how to make my Start Button work

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, 2d-games

I followed a guide to make the space invaders game application but i also have a main menu that i created. I know how to make buttons switch FXML files but the application with the game has no clear FXML file

```
package SpaceInvaders;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Node;

public class MenuController {
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;

    public void start(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SpaceGame.fxml"));
        Parent gameRoot = loader.load();

        Scene gameScene = new Scene(gameRoot);

        Stage gameStage = new Stage();
        gameStage.setScene(gameScene);
        gameStage.show();
    }

    public void showHighscore(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SpaceHighscore.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    @FXML void quitGame(){
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

This is my MenuController that i controlls the FXML i start by running this:

```
package SpaceInvaders;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SpaceApp extends Application{


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {  
     
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

And i want this game file to load when i press start:

```
package SpaceInvaders;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class BedreSpaceApp extends Application {
    private Pane root = new Pane();

    
    
    private double time = 0;
    
    private double tick = 0.016;

    private GameObject player = new GameObject(300, 750, 40, 40, "player", 3, Color.BLUE);
    public Parent createContent() {
        root.setPrefSize(600, 800);

        root.getChildren().add(player);
        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                update();
            }
            
        };
        timer.start();
        newInvaders();
    
        return root;
    }
    
    

    private void newInvaders() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                    GameObject invader = new GameObject(40 + j * 50, 30, 20, 20, "invader", 30, Color.PURPLE);
                    root.getChildren().add(invader);
                }
            }
            else if (i > 0 && i < 3) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                    GameObject invader = new GameObject(40 + j * 50, 30 + i * 30, 20, 20, "invader", 20, Color.CRIMSON);
                    root.getChildren().add(invader);
            }
            }
            else {
                for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                    GameObject invader = new GameObject(40 + j * 50, 30 + i * 30, 20, 20, "invader", 10, Color.HOTPINK);
                    root.getChildren().add(invader);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public List<GameObject> objects() {
        return root.getChildren().stream().map(e -> (GameObject)e).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
        
    public void shoot(GameObject shooter){
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            bullet(shooter);
        }
    }

    private void update(){
        time += tick;

        objects().forEach(item -> {
            switch (item.getType()){

                case "invaderbullet":
                    item.down();

                    if(item.getBoundsInParent().intersects(player.getBoundsInParent())){
                        player.injure(1);
                        item.alive = false;
                    }
                break;
                
                case "playerbullet":
                    item.up();

                    objects().stream().filter(f -> f.getType().equals("invader")).forEach(invader -> {
                        if (item.getBoundsInParent().intersects(invader.getBoundsInParent())) {
                            invader.injure(10);
                            item.alive = false;
                        }
                    });
                    break;

                case "invader":
                    if (time > 2) {
                        if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
                            bullet(item);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().removeIf(n -> {
            GameObject item = (GameObject) n;
            return !item.isAlive();
        });

        if (time > 2) {
            time = 0;
        }
    }
    public void bullet(GameObject shooter) {
        GameObject bullet = new GameObject(shooter.getTranslateX() + 20, shooter.getTranslateY(), 10, 5, shooter.getType() + "bullet", 1, Color.PEACHPUFF);
        root.getChildren().add(bullet);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());
        
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            switch (e.getCode()) {
                case A:
                    player.left();
                    break;
                case D:
                    player.right();
                    break;
                case SPACE:
                    shoot(player);
                    break;
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    
}
```

Comment: You’ll need a private field that holds the current state of the game:  started, or not yet started.  Also, a JavaFX application has one and only one class that extends Application.  It is not correct to have more than one class extending Application.

Comment: Why does your application have two `Application` classes? One of them (`SpaceApp`) has the `start()` method as a no-op, so it won't do anything when you run it.

Comment: I started on [this](https://github.com/sedj601/SpaceInvadersFX) a while back. It's full of issues, but maybe it can help you start.

Comment: Note: In JavaFX, you should only have one class extend `Application`. The application class represents the entire application and its lifecycle. It virtually never makes sense to have more than one. You don't have two applications. You have one application with multiple views, and you should write your code accordingly. Additionally, you may only call `launch` once per _JVM instance_ (i.e., only once per execution of your program).